# how can i use make using powershell on win10

Tags: c

I installed make and gcc on win10.
I tried to write a simple makefile.
When I execute make clean, I find it doesn't work properly.
I found the problem. on win10, make uses cmd instead of powershell, so the shell command I wrote in makefile does not work. Is there any way to change make to use powershell

Comment: I would rather make it use `sh`, like on every other modern OS. That's what [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075)'s port of `make` uses.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [tag:sh] will not work for [tag:powershell] commands.

Comment: @Gerhard My point is that makefiles should be written for the `sh` shell, since it's used by default on most platforms, and you can get it on Windows too.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `SHELL` variable inside of the makefile to the path of powershell wherever that might be.